# ng-grid export to csv, how can I move the link to somewhere else, other than the footer

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

After doing some research about exporting ng-grid data to PDF and CSV, found they've provided plugins for exporting.

pdfPlugin: I need to create a button to trigger the export (found this example, [plnk][1])

cvsPlugin: The link shows in the grid footer. so my question is how can I make a button like what the pdfPlugin to trigger cvs export.

```
[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/t4aEBW?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use angular's template cache for the component you wish to overwrite in the grid. Study the ng-grid debug code for which the index.html provides a link to and read more on $templateCache.
Currently, the button is simply a distinct html tag after the whole grid.
Here you can find some useful configuration options you can pass for the grid:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options 
Such as rowTemplate, headerRowTemplate etc.  One good use would be in headerRow template, you can add another row for filtering or various buttons.
You add them to this object:
 $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData', plugins: [pdfPlugIn] };

Comment: Hi Laurentiu, thanks for the comment. do you know if we can add csvPlugin and pdfPlugin at the same time, like plugins: [csvPlugin, pdfPlugin]. I've tried this, but seems not working.

Comment: Yes, you can add them at the same time. However i am not sure about the way you are trying to add them. That syntax you described is indeed correct for passing plugins as a grid options. These are some examples of plugins https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Plugins . I can't see what you can write insive csvPlugin and pdfPlugin to make what you want work just like that. If you want to manipulate DOM from inside a plugin, i'm not sure that's the way to go. Instead, here you can see more on templating the grid https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating.

Answer (score 0):

There is an angular directive called [ng-csv](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-csv).

It can be used to create downloadable CSV files of arrays and objects.

Find a working example [here](https://asafdav.github.io/ng-csv/example/).

Answer (score 0):

found another solution and it worked pretty well.

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/312_exporting_data_complex